# Two 'add' commands cannot have equal id

Tags: magento-2.1

I am working on Magento 2 extension and I am facing below error.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:79:"Two 'add' commands cannot have equal id (Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule)";
i:1;s:6358:"#0 /home/mcs/html/demo/m2/Module/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Builder.php(43): 
Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Command\Add->chain(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Command\Add))
```

below is **menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>

        <add id="Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule_manager" title="mymodule" module="Vendor_Mymodule" parent="Vendor_General::general" sortOrder="10" resource="Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule_manager" />

        <add id="Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule" title="Manage Text" module="Vendor_Mymodule" sortOrder="11" parent="Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule_manager" action="mymodule/index" resource="Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule"/>

        <add id="Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule_data" title="Manage Data" module="Vendor_Mymodule" sortOrder="11" parent="Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule_manager" action="mymodule/index" resource="Vendor_Mymodule::mymodule"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Please post your menu.xml from your module

Comment: @KeyurShah, I added my menu.xml in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the error message, It looks like you have same `id` in `menu.xml`, you can  see this error message on this file,

`vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Command\Add.php`

```
public function chain(\Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\AbstractCommand $command)
{
    if ($command instanceof \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Command\Add) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Two 'add' commands cannot have equal id (" . $command->getId() . ")");
    }
    return parent::chain($command);
}
```

Please confirm your menu id is different or you have something wrong in `menu.xml`

Comment: Thanks, you were right. It was the issue with id of my menu item.